# Excel data to be inserted into a coredata model

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app that has some data ( static ) that needs to be shipped out with the app. The client gave me this data in Excel(over 300 rows), now I created a model for this in coredata, I was wondering is there a way or a tutorial that shows how can I make an import from excel into my model ? or if someone thinks of a better approach to incorporate this data( SQLLite maybe)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to import CSV data into sqlite3 at the command line; however, it is recommended that you not do this, since Core Data creates sqlite fields that would need to be dealt with.

If you start with CSV, you could look at doing something like this:

http://macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxvi-parsing-csv-data

perhaps with modification to work with your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

To import the data into your application and store it in Core Data I would export the Excel Data to a [CSV file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). That filetype is easy to parse. I don't know about any libraries that parse Excel files directly. Your code does than look like this.

```
NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"path/to/file.csv" usedEncoding:&enc error:nil];
NSArray *lines = [fileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
for (NSString *currentLine in lines) {
    // Handle this line and store in model
    NSArray *fields = [currentLine componentsSeperatedByString:@";"]; // Or other delimiter

    // From the excel file you know which column is which property in the model. 
    // Populate the entity appropriately and store it
}
```

The above code is without guarantee. I didn't test the code.